# Java, drawing e cross

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to code a method which draws a cross in JAVA. (see the photo for an example).

Here is the example:

[image: Example]

Few Questions:

- how do I give an array the dimensions via parameter? It seems that Eclipse needs a number instead of variables for the array dimensions. I thought it is possible to give the method a parameter, how big the dimensions of the array should be.
- Don't get the idea how to tell the loop which one of the array positions should be an X and which one not.
- Here is my code idea so far...it does not really what it should do :) I took "1" instead of "X", so I can do it with an int array.

  public void drawCross(int number){
      int i,j;
      int array[][]=new int[40][40];

  ```
  for(j=1;j<=number;j++){
      for(i=1;i<=number;i++){
          if(array[i]==array[j]){
          array[i][j]=1;
          System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
          }
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
  }
  ```

  }

Thank you in advance.
Pete

Comment: What should be your value of number?

Comment: @Massud for example: 5

Comment: `int array[][] = new int[number][number];` should be possible, what did you try?

Comment: your right, it works :) I thought this was exactly what I tried earlier...

Comment: But now, I get an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5.

Comment: arrays are 0-index based

Comment: @PetePeterson: Arrays are zero-indexed. If there are 10 elements, they range from indexes 0-9, not 1-10 as your for loops use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this does not really seem homework, the solution

```
int[][] array = new int[number][number];

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < number; j++){
        if (i == j || i == number - 1 - j) {
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
        System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

1. `int[][] a` is the conventional way. `int a[][]` is syntactic sugar for C programmers.
2. In math `i` normally is the row, and `j` the column, so switched the for-loops.
3. Arrays are indexed from 0.
4. The condition should say whether one is on one of both diagonals, so only concerns the indices i and j.
5. `||` is OR, and `&&` is AND (should you not already know).
6. As you see, the matrix `array` is not needed

So:

```
boolean isOnDiagonal = i == j || i == number - 1 - j;
System.out.print(isOnDiagonal ? "X " : ". "); // if-then-else operator.
```

Comment: Thank you! Am I right, that the -1 in "number-1-j" is needed, because an array starts with 0?

Comment: Yes, indices are 0, 1, ..., number - 1, where number == array.length.